# Deleting everything that is enclosed with quotes or is a number in Python?

Tags: python

Lets say I have this string:

```
myString="'Hello'+yes+'Whats hello'6"
```

I am looking for a way to delete everything enclosed in quotes

So, it would become:

```
"+yes+"
```

Because, 'Hello'  and 'Whats hello' are enclosed by quotes. And 6 is a number.

Is there a way to do this? Maybe using Regular Expressions? I tried doing this with a For Loop, but I guess my logic wasn't that great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Python 2.7.2 (default, Aug 19 2011, 20:41:43) [GCC] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r"('[^']*'|\d)", "", "'Hello'+yes+'Whats hello'6")
'+yes+'
>>>
```

`(...|...)` matches one thing or another; `'[^']*'` matches anything but a quote inside quotes; `\d` matches digits.  `re.sub(pattern, replacement, string)` replaces each instance of pattern with the replacement.

ps note that the `'` in the result are just python putting quotes around the string! (you can use single or double quotes in python; python prefers single when printing strings, if the string itself doesn't contain any).

**update** - is this what you want?

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r"('[^']*'|(?<![a-zA-Z])\d(?![a-zA-Z]))", "", "'Hello'+yes+'Whats hello'6")
'+yes+'
>>> re.sub(r"('[^']*'|(?<![a-zA-Z])\d(?![a-zA-Z]))", "", "+ye5s")
'+ye5s'
```

Comment: Wow, that was quick, Great! I need to wait 10 minutes to accept, Thanks very much

Comment: Hmm, Im just wondering, If I had for example: "'Hello'+ye5s" that it would return "+ye5s". I would really like to only remove numbers if they are alone. Another example: "'Hello'+4whoo+4*9" would return "+4whoo+*", Yes, I don't expect you to do this but if you could and know how to that would be cool but your current answer is great.

Comment: what do you mean "alone"?  that they don't have a letter on either side?